# Angular service foreach $q.promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, angular-promise

i have the following function:

```
    this.getBenchmarkData = function () {
    var benchmarkData = [];
    var d = $q.defer();
    users.forEach(function(user){
        var dataArray = [];
        modules.forEach(function (module) {
            $http.get(api.getUrl('teamUserBenchmark', [user.user_id, module.id, user.team_id]))
                .success(function (response) {
                    response.forEach(function(result){
                        dataArray.push(result.score);
                    })
                });
        });

        benchmarkData.push(dataArray);

    });
    d.resolve(benchmarkData);

    return d.promise
}
```

Problem is that the `d.resolve(benchmarkData)` is runned before actual data has been put into it.

I know that this is a problem with the async `$http` task. However i am not sure how to fix it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not resolving promise correctly, You should collect all the promise in array and then use `$q.all` to resolve the deferred promise

**Code**

```
this.getBenchmarkData = function () {
var benchmarkData = [];
var d = $q.defer(), promise = [];
users.forEach(function(user){
    var dataArray = [];
    modules.forEach(function (module) {
        var currentPromise = $http.get(api.getUrl('teamUserBenchmark', [user.user_id, module.id, user.team_id]))
            .success(function (response) {
                response.forEach(function(result){
                    dataArray.push(result.score);
                })
            });
        promise.push(currentPromise); //<--creating promise array here
    });
});
$q.all(promise).then(function(){ 
   benchmarkData.push(dataArray); //added whole data.
   d.resolve(benchmarkData); //resolved after all promise gets completed
});


return d.promise
```

Comment: @downvoter can i know the reason why it is down voted?

Comment: you should populate benchmarkData after currentPromise was resolved, but it is minor, the main idea is correct

Comment: @EugeneSafronov Ahh..I missed that, You are correct.. I updated the answer..Thanks :)

Comment: it would be easier to use `map` instead of `[] + forEach + push`